# Is it possible to add an Android widget to app in Uno Platform?

Tags: android, uwp, widget, uno-platform

I would love to add a widget to my Android app, which is being developed using Uno Platform.

I found some tutorials how to do it in Xamarin, but don't know if it will work.

One of the tutorials:
https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno Platform on Android is based on vanilla Xamarin, and you'll be able to use everything that Xamarin provides.

You'll need to place your android-specific code in your `.Android` head project (not in the shared project), and the use `#if __ANDROID__` blocks to ensure that the [android specific code](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html) is only used on the android target.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the answer, I was looking for.